# Empty Field Notification View?

Tags: views, 7, notifications

My website has a content type with about 15 fields. Now I don't have all the data to fill the fields all the time. I've got close to 1000 entries in this content type.

Is there any module that can work as a Notifier. Ex: I've chosen to have Content Type A selected and the module tells me how many Entries that are not 100% filled and what fields are missing. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try any one of the module as per your requirement.

[Content Complete](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_complete)

> Content Complete is a CCK extension module that allows to tag CCK fields needed for completion (CCK Complete). The module checks the tagged fields against the content provided for those content types, and computes a complete percentage that can be shown to the user.

[image]

[Field Complete](https://www.drupal.org/project/fc)

> In some situations you want to mark an entity field to indicate it should be completed but not enforce its completion at that time. This module extends the choice between Required and Not required to "desirable" completion.
>
> This module overcomes the problems with the (otherwise excellent) [Content Complete](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_complete) module which cannot cope with field collections or fields that link to other entities.

Hope the following links give you clear ideas on how to use Content Complete module.

[Measure node completion in Drupal, part 1](http://nuvole.org/blog/2010/apr/05/measure-node-completion-drupal-part-1)

[Measure node completion in Drupal, part 2](http://nuvole.org/node/9)